# com.blobcity.db.exceptions.InternalAdapterException: Unable to communicate with the database at this time

Tags: java, database, database-connection, bigdata

I am getting the following error when performing a basic insert operation on Infinitum database. I am sure I have the database running as I am able to connect to it and operate on it over CLI.

The error message is:

```html
Exception in thread "main" com.blobcity.db.exceptions.InternalAdapterException: Unable to communicate with the database at this time
 at com.blobcity.db.QueryExecuter.executeQuery(QueryExecuter.java:71)
 at com.blobcity.db.QueryExecuter.executeBql(QueryExecuter.java:30)
 at com.blobcity.db.CloudStorage.postRequest(CloudStorage.java:728)
 at com.blobcity.db.CloudStorage.insert(CloudStorage.java:650)
 at com.blobcity.db.CloudStorage.insert(CloudStorage.java:381)
 at com.blobcity.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost/rest/bquery
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1888)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1883)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1882)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1455)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
 at com.blobcity.db.QueryExecuter.executeQuery(QueryExecuter.java:57)
 ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost/rest/bquery
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1838)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
 at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
 at com.blobcity.db.QueryExecuter.executeQuery(QueryExecuter.java:55)
 ... 5 more
```

My main method that creates the error is:

```html
package com.blobcity;

import com.blobcity.db.config.Credentials;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Credentials.init("localhost", "root", "root", "mydb");
        
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.setId("1");
        hello.setRandom(new Random().nextInt());
        hello.insert();
    }
}
```

And the entity class for which I have created the corresponding table is:

```html
package com.blobcity;

import com.blobcity.db.CloudStorage;
import com.blobcity.db.annotations.Entity;
import com.blobcity.db.annotations.Primary;

@Entity
public class Hello extends CloudStorage{
    @Primary
    public String id;
    public int random;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getRandom() {
        return random;
    }

    public void setRandom(int random) {
        this.random = random;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the port number while setting the `Credentials`. The default port for connecting to Infinitum database is `10111`, unless you have changed this port the following should work

```html
Credentials.init("localhost:10111", "root", "root", "mydb");
```